# Get canvas and context from video element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw on a video element context in html5 using javascript like this:

```
function draw(video,context,w,h) {
    if(video.paused || video.ended) return false;
    context.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
    setTimeout(draw,20,video,context,w,h);
}
```

but i only have access to the video element, i dont have the context variable or any canvas, since that part of the javascript is not available to me, i only have that one variable "video" which was created somewhere else maybe something like this

```
   var video = document.createElement('video');
```

Is there anyway i can retrieve the context from the video element?

like document.canvas.context.video or something like that? sorry Im a real java script novice.

Thanks

Comment: This article has the exact code you posted http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/ . Anyway, this question is not describing a specific problem with your own attempts, thus should be edited or closed.

Comment: Nope no way, neither the canvas element, nor the video do know each other. But if you canvas is in the document, you can use any DOM selection method (e.g `document.querySelector('canvas')` if it's the first one)